# pear environment variables causes error

Tags: php, pear, windows-server-2012

I use Windows Server 2012 and PHP 5.3.13.

PHP is installed fine, and I try to install pear now.

I ran the `go-pear.bat` and keep hitting Enter, (using the defaults I guess).

Then ran the `PEAR_ENV`.

I checked the environment vars and chenged the values of `PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe`, where my `php.exe` lives. Both for Admin and System vars.

Now, when I type `pear` to command line I get the message `syntax error, unexpected '(' in Unknown on line 14`. I click OK and I get the options for pear.

I guess is caused because of the `(x86)` part in the values?

If I go to the website I am working, PHP cannot connect to the database. Is that a pear's fault? Or is another issue?

Thanks in advance

PS

Inside `php.ini`, the only line that is not a comment and has to do with `include_path` is this one `include_path=".;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear"`

Comment: Windows like the directories with spaces to be in quotes. Maybe try `include_path=".;\"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\pear\""` so it has the quotes it would usually use?

Comment: @Jessica I try ia nd now I get `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting TC_DOLLAR_CURL or TC_QUOTED_STRING or "" in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini on line 1932`.I hit OK, then I get `syntax error, unexpected '(' in Unknown on line 14`. I hit OK again, and then I get the options for pear

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because PHP “incorrectly” processes a line.

Open the `pear.bat` file find the following line, at the bottom

`"%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%" -C -d output_buffering=1 -d safe_mode=0 -d open_basedir="" -d auto_prepend_file="" -d auto_append_file="" -d variables_order=EGPCS -d register_argc_argv="On" -d include_path="%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%" -f "%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%pearcmd.php" -- %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`

and replace the `include_path="%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%"` part with `"include_path='%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%'"`

The double quotes keeps shell happy, while the single quotes are for PHP to use.

Taken from Nasir's blog [here](http://www.dnasir.com/2010/12/02/tutorial-how-to-install-pear-on-iis7/). Worked for me